# Problema al sincronizar Git con Plesk

Tags: git, github, plesk

Tengo un servidor con Plesk Onyx Versión 17.8.11 y con el SO CentOS 6.10.
Tiene instalada la extensión Git en su versión .1.5-250. No se puede actualizar la extensión por la versión de Plesk y del SO.

Cuando se quiere añadir un repositorio alojado en GitHub, da error. La extensión solamente pide la dirección del sitio remoto, indicando que se soportan los protocolos HTTPS y SSH.
[image: Plesk-Git]

Al indicar la dirección por HTTPS copiada de GitHub, se muestra el siguiente error:

[image: Error Plesk]

Si pruebo por SSH y copio la clave en GitHub, dice que la clave generada no es lo suficientemente segura. He probado cambiarla en la carpeta /.ssh y añadiendo las reglas al fichero config para que conecte por el puerto 443:

Host github.com

User git

Port 443

Una vez realizado esto, está un rato pensando y aparece en Plesk el mensaje de error:
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

¿Sabéis si hay alguna forma de sincronizar el repositorio con esta versión de la extensión GIT?
Si es preferible, mejor por el protocolo HTTPS.

Gracias